# how to keep <div> and <img> outside of <div> aligned

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS Code:

```
.blackbox {
    background: black;
    width: 17px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In my HTML file, I call the following.

```
<div class="blackbox">
  10
</div>
<img src="icon-local.png">
<img src="icon-national.png">
```

How can I keep the box that is rendered via CSS call and the images called via img tag on the same horizontal line?

The goal is to create something that looks similar to this, but with the CSS box in front of the other icons. Example Image: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqwgr.png)

Thanks in advance!

Ken

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` or `display:table`.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="blackbox">10</div>
    <img src="icon-local.png" />
    <img src="icon-national.png" />
</div>
```

And the css

```
.parent div, .parent img {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* IE7 hack */
    zoom:1 /* IE7 */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your blackbox class `inline` or `inline-block`:

```
.blackbox {
    display:inline-block;
    background: black;
    width: 17px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default display for `<div>` elements are "block" (that is, it adds a line break before and after it) so you could just use:

```
.blackbox {
    background: black;
    width: 17px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

Notice the `display: inline;`

Also, `display: inline-block;` is also useful in many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `div` as `display:inline-block` and float your images to the left so that you have the same result as your example image. Floating your images can be avoided if you change your HTML and have the images before the div. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G5Q4k/1/

Comment: See my edit. I implemented exactly what the example image is showing.